# Reading posts from facebook groups in python

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api

I try to read posts from facebook groups I'm a member in using python.

Using the facebook-sdk and an access token from facebook from developers I get a permission error.

Is there a way to read the posts using an access token or any other way?

Comment: If you do not have admin access, then a group admin would have to "install" your app on the group first, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/groups-api